# Re-routing audio into skype with a separate program on windows

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, microphone

Recently skype stopped working with my microphone (what I hear is sent, not what I say). It works fine in everything else, but skype doesn't work well with it and I use skype to communicate with a lot of my friends. Is there any way to use a separate program to record my audio and stream it to skype as a virtual microphone? (Needs to work on Windows; I don't get this problem on linux).

Comment: Before going for such a turn, let us know whether you checked  volume settings in Windows and also audio settings in skype or not?.

Answer (score 0):

If you unplugged your microphone for a bit, then Skype will have defaulted to a loopback/"stereo mix" input device. Try checking in Skype's settings (Tools>Options>Audio Settings) and see what its microphone input is set to. If it's not set to your microphone, then change it.

I'm going to advise against rerouting and say **find the cause of the problem**

Comment: It's set to my normal microphone, and there aren't any other choices if I go to the advanced screen.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling your sound card/chip drivers